# What speaks against single-page apps from a user experience point of view?

Tags: html, single-page-application

I like them more and wonder why they are not more common. Explanations involving caching or SEO make sense to me, but I don't see them as directly driven by user experience considerations. In which way are traditional sites with page reloads better for the user?

Comment: You might receive good answers on this site: http://ux.stackexchange.com/ 
 :) Stack Overflow is for programming/development issues, not so much about theory

Comment: I think the web-development world moves quickly and is changing over to SPAs quickly. Despite the SEO issues (there are ways around it) SPAs generally provide a much better UX experience. I haven't heard of many new apps being developed that are not mostly if not entirely a SPA. On the other hand, there is lots of legacy code. Not as easy to switch quickly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally I think the best argument for normal page reloads from a user's perspective is that when you do that it's much harder to break many basic browser functions. In general the back/forward buttons work, bookmarking works, copying and pasting links works, history works, page titles work, getting an error page when a server call fails works, everything just works as expected. For free.

I have seen single page application implemented in a way that breaks one or more of the above more times than I can count.

It's naturally not a problem if you get it *just right* (and then it will in general be nicer to use), but not all sites do.

Just as an example here's a screenshot how a site that is a SPA and justifiedly so (they have a music player that you don't want to interrupt with page loads), broke a basic browser function in a way they might not even have thought of. I was trying to find a song I recently listened to but couldn't remember the exact title... but because of the SPAness the page titles weren't properly reflected in my browser history.

[image: SoundCloud browser history screenshot]